# Getting access to Hive using .Net Core? (Incompatible libraries)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hadoop, hive, .net-core

I've been searching around for quite some time now, to see if it is possible to connect a .Net Core application to a (hadoop) Hive service?

I've found a few libraries that generally are available for .Net to connect to Hive, but when I try to download these packages and restore my .Net Core application, I get errors saying that the installed package is not available/compatible for .Net Core.

I was wondering if someone out there have any knowledge of whether it is possible?

For now, all I want is basically just to input connection variables (ip, port number, username and password) and see if I can start writing commands to Hive to get data from it. I'm already using a MySql Database, to store data and that connection is up and running using EF7 for my .Net Core application. So for now I just want the following function to work:

```
public bool gotConnectionToHive(string ip, int portNr, string username, string password)
{
    bool connected = false;
    //get connection to Hive.. (using input parameters)
    //set connected = true if connection is live, else leave it be

    return connected;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it but may be it's worth posting this as an issue in .net core github community or respective external hive libraries community to get some useful response.

Comment: Great idea. I might do that later if I find the time and no one has answered my post :P

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: I didn't post it as an issue on .net core github, and looked elsewhere for solutions. However I didn't find a solution. Sorry :(